# Changing android action bar tab with actionBarTabStyle throws Exception

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is my code

```
 <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item> 

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item> 
</style>

  <!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
     <item name="android:background">#009688</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTabStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
     <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">32dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">32dp</item> 
</style>
```

--Here is V-14 code

```
 <!-- none-->
```

Here is V-11 code

I am getting below error. Does anyone knows what is wrong here ? I have added the file it is complaining about which is `res/drawable-xhdpi/actionbar_tab_indicator.xml`.

```
03-17 00:42:08.190: E/AndroidRuntime(14661): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 00:42:08.190: E/AndroidRuntime(14661): java.lang.RuntimeException:
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.application/com.myapp.application.MainActivity}:
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-xhdpi/actionbar_tab_indicator.xml 
from drawable resource ID #0x7f020059
```

Comment: show your main layout in activity

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting below error. Does anyone knows what is wrong here ? I have added the file it is complaining about which is res/drawable-xhdpi/actionbar_tab_indicator.xml.

Why are you putting it in `drawable-xhdpi` folder, put it in `drawable` folder, if its a drawable.

Comment: I did not put it in xhdpi folder, It was one of those weird errors. But Hit and trial resolved it for me by adding  this code to v-11 and v-14    `<style name="MyActionBarTabStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    
    </style>` adding it here so that it might help someone else